# Error 500 (Internal Server Error) while uploading pictures

Tags: node.js, heroku, cloudinary

When I'm trying to upload pictures with cloudinary I get an error 500. 
It does not work either locally or when my server is deployed on Heroku.

I have set up the config var in both Heroku and an env. file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJxeq.png

In the console, I get this error:

> POST https://world-map-mq.herokuapp.com/country/create 500 (Internal Server Error) .
>
> Error: Request failed with status code 500
>
> at createError (createError.js:17) .
>
> at settle (settle.js:19) .
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60) .

In Heroku my log is like this:

> 2019-07-12T14:16:14.091247+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started
>
> 2019-07-12T14:16:15.212574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/country/create" host=world-map-mq.herokuapp.com request_id=d6c8ca5b-18a4-48e2-9846-36911d07c5cd fwd="92.151.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=204 bytes=494 protocol=https
>
> 2019-07-12T14:16:15.821978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/country/create" host=world-map-mq.herokuapp.com request_id=1eab82fd-df0c-4ad4-950f-17592cd6257e fwd="92.151.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=500ms status=500 bytes=499 protocol=https

The upload is a callback:

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
require("dotenv").config();
const uid2 = require("uid2");

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

const uploadPictures = (req, res, next) => {
  const files = req.body.files;
  let filesUploaded = 0;

  if (files && files.length) {
    files.forEach(file => {
      // Je crée un nom spécifique pour le fichier
      const name = String(uid2(16));
      cloudinary.uploader.upload(
        file,
        {
          public_id: `/country/${req.body._id}/${name}`
        },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            return res.status(500).json("Une erreur est survenue");
          }
          pictures.push(result);
          filesUploaded++;
          if (filesUploaded === files.length) {
            req.pictures = pictures.map(pic => pic.secure_url);

            console.log(req.pictures);
            // ... et je poursuis ma route avec `next()`
            next();
          }
        }
      );
    });
  } else {

    next();
  }
};

module.exports = uploadPictures;
```

Here is the route part where I'm using the call back:

```
router.post("/country/create", uploadPictures, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const countryKnown = await Country.findOne({
      countryVisited: req.body.countryVisited
    });
    // const countryVisitedCode = ;
    if (countryKnown) {
      res.json({ message: "Country already existing" });
    } else {
      const newCountry = new Country({
        countryVisited: req.body.countryVisited,
        countryVisitedCode: countries.getCode(req.body.countryVisited),
        description: req.body.description,
        title: req.body.title,
        pictures: req.pictures
      });
      await newCountry.save(function(err) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          _id: newCountry._id,
          countryVisited: newCountry.countryVisited,
          countryVisitedCode: newCountry.countryVisitedCode,
          description: newCountry.description,
          title: newCountry.title,
          pictures: newCountry.pictures,
          message: "Created"
        });
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("yolo", { error });
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

// 2*1 READ
router.get("/country", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const country = await Country.find();
    res.json(country);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

Here is part the front in React  :

```js
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://world-map-mq.herokuapp.com/country/create",
        {
          countryVisited: this.state.countryVisited,
          description: this.state.description,
          title: this.state.title,
          files: this.state.files
        }
      );
      this.setState({
        countryVisited: "",
        description: "",
        title: "",
        files: []
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({ error: error });
      alert({ error: error.message });
    }
  };


 handleFiles = files => {
    const newFiles = [...this.state.files, ...files.base64];
    this.setState({ files: newFiles });
  };

render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      console.log("loading");
      // ce que l'on veut render avant le chargement
      return null;
    }
    // ce que l'on veut render avant le chargement
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

 <ReactFileReader
            fileTypes={[".png", ".jpg"]}
            base64={true}
            multipleFiles={true}
            handleFiles={this.handleFiles}
          >
            <div>Choisir une photo</div>
          </ReactFileReader>
   <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
        </form>
      </div>

 );
  }
}
```

Could you put me in the right direction to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there any other relevant output before the single Heroku log line you're showing us? Normally this would be preceded by a traceback or similar.

Comment: Hello, thansk for your reply and for the tips. I have edited my post to delete the pictures. I just left the configuration variable of Heroku has an image.

Comment: There is just one more line that seems in the Heroku logs after the Server Starting and before the error. I also added it in the original post

Comment: You're stomping on the error message: `if (error) { return res.status(500).json("Une erreur est survenue"); }`. Don't just say "an error has occurred"; use the `error`. Include it in your result, or at least print it to `stderr` so it's included in your `heroku logs`. It probably contains more helpful information.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for you reply. I have changed my error message to `error: error.message` but the logs stay the same. I'm not sure what you mean by "print it to `stderr`. Can you tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just changing the error message wouldn't change the logs; it would change the HTTP response. When I say "print to `stderr`" I mean that you can literally print the result out to your standard error stream (`stderr`). I'm not sure how that works with Node.js; the best solution is probably to use whatever the standard logging facility is. You should be able to configure a logger that outputs to `stderr` (or `stdout`, which should work too).